# Find test statistic given a confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

Based on intervention data (2 sample dependent) I was given a confidence interval and asked to provide the test statistic. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I can find the mean by:

CI+ - CI- = range

range/2 = margin of error (MOE)

CI+ - MOE = mean

CI- + MOE = mean

I'm given n and that alpha is at the 95% confidence level. Am I on the right track and what am I missing?

Comment: If you know the CI is symmetric, then I think you are on the right track. If you calculate "mean" this way, it is equal to the test statistic. Although, you should rephrase the following in your question: CI+ - CI- = range and range/2=MOE.

Comment: @StijnDeVuyst the test statistic equation would be `t=mean/SD/sqrt(n)` Why is the mean equal to t?

Comment: I am not saying the mean equals t, I just followed your formulas in the original question. If you do that, what you call "mean" will be equal to the test statistic. So you are responsible for the confusion. In fact, again if you know the CI is symmetric (!), the test statistic t will be in the center of the confidence interval. Therefore, t = (CI+ + CI-)/2.